# How do you choose between 2 random variables using the random module?

Tags: python

Here's what I want to do:

```
import random

a = 1
b = 2

# choose between these 2 variables (a and b) with probability

# 50% to choose one

print(# the function that chooses)

output: either 1 or 2
```

Some people suggested me to use `random.choice`, but that doesn't work.
Others said `random.random`, but it doesn't work either.
Is there a probability module or something??

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? How are you using it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can only tell you why something "doesn't work" if you show us exactly what you tried, exactly what you think should happen, exactly what happened instead, and how that is different. Please read [ask]. Also, you should [try to figure things out yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), for example by reading [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). It's [easy to find](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=random+site%3Apython.org).

Answer (score 3):

`random.choice()` works, you just need to pass the choices as a tuple or a list:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 3
>>> random.choice((a, b))
5
>>> random.choice((a, b))
3
>>> random.choice((a, b))
3
>>> random.choice((a, b))
5
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice()` definitely works:

> The choice() method returns a randomly selected element from the specified sequence. The sequence can be a string, a range, a list, a tuple or any other kind of sequence.

```
import random
#100 cases
for i in range(100):
    k = random.choice((1, 2))
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
2
1
2
2
2
2
1
2
2
2
1
1
2
1
2
1
...
```

You just weren't passing the options into a list/tuple.

You can also utilize `random.randint`:
However, if you were to use this to pick between larger numbers like 1 and 100, it would not work:

> The randint() method returns an integer number selected element from the specified range. (Inclusive)

```
import random
#100 cases
for i in range(100):
    k = random.randint(1, 2)
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
1
2
2
2
1
2
1
1
1
...
```